# Triggering CSS animation on JS textContent change

Tags: javascript, css

I am basically creating a simple quiz app. Right now when the question is wrong, it updates the textContent of the question space to let the user know that they were wrong. Then after a setTimeOut, it changes it back to the question again.

That works fine as things stand. Right now though those changes happen instantly and I want them to fade out then in. Ive been trying to figure out just by changing opacity though right now nothing is affect it. So I figure I am either setting the animation incorrectly (very possible), or I am doing something wrong in the JavaScript.

So what I am looking for:

1. FadeIn the new textContent telling the user that the question was wrong
2. Wait 1 second
   3.FadeOut the newTextContent and replace with the old question content.

For 1 and 3: I am thinking it can be done creating a simple Keyframe animation then reversing it. (opacity 100 to 0% then opacity 0% to 100).

2. I can wait the 1 second with my setTimeout as things stand now, I just am not sure how to make sure the animation triggers to do the fadeEffect.

I am using Vanilla Js (prefer no Jquery) could someone point me in the right direction here?

Jsfiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/ubw97kfe/
Ive added comments to point to the particular code elements I am referencing.

```js
// Title of Question Set
const title = document.querySelector(".input_title-input");

// Array of Questions
const questions = [];
let chosen = [];

// Selected Question
let qChosen = [];

// Toggles if a new question is selected
let toggle = 0;

// Selecting Inputs and Button
let question = document.querySelector(".input_question-input");
let answer = document.querySelector(".input_answer-input");
let submit = document.querySelector(".input_submit-button");
let display = document.querySelector(".input_display");
let card = document.querySelector(".card_container");
let start = document.querySelector(".input_start-btn");
let guessInput = document.querySelector(".guess_input");
let submitGuess = document.querySelector(".submitGuess");
let nextQuestion = document.querySelector(".nextQuestion");

// Select all display items
let displayItems = document.getElementsByClassName("input_display-item");

// Select LI quiz card values
let cardQuestion = document.querySelector(".quiz_question");
let cardAnswer = document.querySelector(".quiz_answer");

// Event Listener on Submit Button for Display Items Idividually
submit.addEventListener("click", function() {
    if (question.value === "" || answer.value === "") {
        question.classList.toggle("error");
        answer.classList.toggle("error");
    } else {
        createObj();

        let trashCan = createDisplayItem();
        trashCan.dataset.index = questions.length - 1;
        trashCan.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
            start.disabled = true;
            questions.splice(this.dataset.index, 1);
            // this.parentNode.remove();
            let thisItem = this.parentNode;
            fadeOutIn(thisItem, 1000);

            
            console.log(questions.length);
        });
        inputReset();
        toggle = questions.length;
        start.removeAttribute("disabled");


        console.log(questions.length);
    }
});

start.addEventListener("click", function() {
    generateCard();
    hideInputs();
});




/* ============================================
==============================================*/

// Event Listener to test if guess is correct
submitGuess.addEventListener("click", function() {
    if (guessInput.value.toLowerCase() === qChosen.answer.toLowerCase()) {
        card.classList.toggle("flip");
        submitGuess.disabled = true;
    } else {
        // Insert wrong message here
        cardQuestion.textContent = "You have guessed incorrectly. Please Try Again";
        // SetTimeout to reset back to Chosen Question
        setTimeout(function(){
            cardQuestion.textContent = qChosen.question;
        }, 1000);
    }
});


/* ============================================
==============================================*/


// Selects the Next question
nextQuestion.addEventListener("click", function() {
    card.classList.toggle("flip");
    guessInput.value = "";
    submitGuess.disabled = false;
    setTimeout(generateCard, 1000);
});

// Create The object for inclusion to array
function createObj() {
    let obj = {};
    obj.question = question.value;
    obj.answer = answer.value;
    questions.push(obj);
}

// Resets inputs to blank after submit
function inputReset() {
    question.value = "";
    answer.value = "";
    if (question.classList.contains("error")) {
        question.classList.toggle("error");
        answer.classList.toggle("error");
    }
}

// Creates Each Display Item
function createDisplayItem() {
    // Create new Div
    let newUl = document.createElement("ul");

    // Create Li and Image Elements
    let liQuestion = document.createElement("li");
    let liAnswer = document.createElement("li");
    let trashCan = document.createElement("img");

    // Set img src
    trashCan.src = "../assets/trash.svg";

    // Set classes
    newUl.className = "input_display-item";
    liQuestion.className = "input_display-question";
    liAnswer.className = "input_display-answer";
    trashCan.className = "input_display-delete";

    // Set LI textContent
    liQuestion.textContent = question.value;
    liAnswer.textContent = answer.value;

    // Append Children
    display.appendChild(newUl);
    newUl.appendChild(liQuestion);
    newUl.appendChild(liAnswer);
    return newUl.appendChild(trashCan);
}

//Generating Card Information per question
function generateCard() {
    random();
    if (toggle < 0) {
        cardQuestion.textContent = "There are no more questions left";
        cardAnswer.textContent = "There are no more questions left";
    } else {
        cardQuestion.textContent = qChosen.question;
        cardAnswer.textContent = qChosen.answer;
    }
}

// Choses a random value for the selection set
function random() {
    if (questions.length === 0) {
        toggle = -1;
    } else {
        let num = Math.floor(Math.random() * questions.length);
        chosen = questions.splice(num, 1).concat(chosen);
        qChosen = chosen[0];
    }
}

// hides all the inputs when start quiz is selected
function hideInputs(){
    for(let i = 0; i < displayItems.length; i++){
        fadeOutIn(displayItems[i], 1000);
    }
}

// FadeOut the display items when trashCan is clicked.
function fadeOutIn(elem, speed){
    if(!elem.style.opacity){
        elem.style.opacity = 1;
    }

    var outInterval = setInterval(function(){
        elem.style.opacity -= 0.02;
        if(elem.style.opacity <=0){
            clearInterval(outInterval);
            elem.remove();
        }
    }, speed/50)
}
```

```css
/** Variables
 ---------------------------------------------------------*/
/** Reset
 ---------------------------------------------------------*/
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0; }

*,
*::before,
*::after {
  -webkit-box-sizing: inherit;
  box-sizing: inherit; }

html {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 62.5%; }

body {
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 1.5;
  font-size: 2rem;
  background-color: #bdbdc7; }

/** Primary Container
 ---------------------------------------------------------*/
.container {
  max-width: 180rem;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex; }

.flex {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center; }

.fadeOut {
  visibility: hidden;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-out; }

/** Input Section
 ---------------------------------------------------------*/
input[type="text"] {
  padding: 0.5rem;
  width: auto;
  min-width: 100%;
  line-height: 2rem; }

.input {
  width: 40rem;
  height: 100vh;
  padding: 1rem;
  background-color: #ccc;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-align: start;
  -ms-flex-align: start;
  align-items: flex-start;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column; }
  .input_title {
    width: 100%;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
    -ms-flex-direction: column;
    flex-direction: column; }
    .input_title-label {
      display: -webkit-box;
      display: -ms-flexbox;
      display: flex;
      -webkit-box-pack: center;
      -ms-flex-pack: center;
      justify-content: center; }
    .input_title-input {
      padding: 0.5rem; }
  .input_question {
    width: 100%;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
    -ms-flex-direction: column;
    flex-direction: column; }
    .input_question-label {
      display: -webkit-box;
      display: -ms-flexbox;
      display: flex;
      -webkit-box-pack: center;
      -ms-flex-pack: center;
      justify-content: center; }
    .input_question-input {
      padding: 0.5rem; }
  .input_answer {
    width: 100%;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
    -ms-flex-direction: column;
    flex-direction: column; }
    .input_answer-label {
      display: -webkit-box;
      display: -ms-flexbox;
      display: flex;
      -webkit-box-pack: center;
      -ms-flex-pack: center;
      justify-content: center; }
    .input_answer-input {
      padding: 0.5rem; }
  .input_question-input.error, .input_answer-input.error {
    border: 2px red solid; }
  .input_submit {
    width: 100%; }
    .input_submit-button {
      margin-top: 1rem;
      padding: 0 1.5rem; }
  .input_start {
    width: 100%; }
  .input_display {
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    padding: 2rem 0 1rem 0; }
    .input_display-item {
      margin-bottom: 1rem;
      padding: .2rem 2rem;
      text-transform: capitalize;
      background-color: #fff;
      border-radius: 1rem;
      list-style: none;
      display: -webkit-box;
      display: -ms-flexbox;
      display: flex;
      -webkit-box-pack: justify;
      -ms-flex-pack: justify;
      justify-content: space-between;
      -webkit-box-align: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
      align-items: center; }
    .input_display-item:nth-child(odd) {
      background-color: #aaa;
      border-radius: 1rem; }
    .input_display-delete {
      height: 1.8rem;
      width: 1.8rem; }

.input :not(.input_display) div {
  padding-bottom: 2rem; }

/** Quiz Card
 ---------------------------------------------------------*/
.card {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%; }
  .card_container {
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -webkit-perspective: 1000px;
    perspective: 1000px;
    width: 60rem;
    margin: 1rem;
    cursor: pointer; }
    .card_container .front {
      -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg);
      transform: rotateY(0deg);
      -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
      transform-style: preserve-3d; }
      .card_container .front:after {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        z-index: 1;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        content: "";
        display: block;
        opacity: 0.6;
        background-color: #000;
        -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
        backface-visibility: hidden;
        border-radius: 10px; }
    .card_container .back {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      width: 100%;
      background-color: #cedce7;
      background: linear-gradient(45deg, #dedce7 0%, #596a72 100%);
      -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
      transform: rotateY(180deg);
      -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
      transform-style: preserve-3d; }
    .card_container .front,
    .card_container .back {
      background-color: red;
      background-size: cover;
      background-position: center;
      -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.7s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.2, 0.2, 1);
      transition: -webkit-transform 0.7s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.2, 0.2, 1);
      transition: transform 0.7s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.2, 0.2, 1);
      transition: transform 0.7s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.2, 0.2, 1), -webkit-transform 0.7s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.2, 0.2, 1);
      transition: transform 0.7s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.2, 0.2, 1);
      -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
      backface-visibility: hidden;
      text-align: center;
      min-height: 500px;
      height: auto;
      border-radius: 10px;
      color: #fff;
      font-size: 1.5rem; }

.flip {
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.7s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.2, 0.2, 1);
  transition: -webkit-transform 0.7s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.2, 0.2, 1);
  transition: transform 0.7s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.2, 0.2, 1);
  transition: transform 0.7s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.2, 0.2, 1), -webkit-transform 0.7s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.2, 0.2, 1);
  transition: transform 0.7s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.2, 0.2, 1); }
  .flip .back {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg);
    transform: rotateY(0deg);
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transform-style: preserve-3d; }
  .flip .front {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
    transform: rotateY(-180deg);
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transform-style: preserve-3d; }

.inner {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%) translateZ(60px) scale(0.94);
  transform: translateY(-50%) translateZ(60px) scale(0.94);
  top: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 2rem;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  outline: 1px solid transparent;
  -webkit-perspective: inherit;
  perspective: inherit;
  z-index: 2; }


/* The particular element applying the animation
==============================================*/

.quiz_question {
  animation: fade 10s linear; }

/* ============================================
==============================================*/



.front .inner p {
  font-size: 2rem;
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
  position: relative; }

.card_container-guess {
  padding-top: 2rem; }
  .card_container-guess .guess_input {
    width: 2rem;
    margin: 1rem auto;
    padding: 1rem;
    border-radius: 1rem;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.55), 0px 1px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.55), 0px 1px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
    border: 1px solid #666;
    opacity: 0.6;
    outline: none; }
    .card_container-guess .guess_input:hover, .card_container-guess .guess_input:focus {
      opacity: .8;
      color: #08c;
      -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.25), inset 0px 3px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
      box-shadow: 0px 1px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.25), inset 0px 3px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25); }
  .card_container-guess-buttons {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-pack: justify;
    -ms-flex-pack: justify;
    justify-content: space-between; }
    .card_container-guess-buttons .btnNew {
      margin: 1rem 2rem; }

.btnNew {
  height: 5rem;
  width: 12rem;
  margin: 1.5rem 3rem 1rem 1rem;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: #333;
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#f4f1ee), to(#fff));
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #f4f1ee, #fff);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 8px 30px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), inset 0px 4px 1px 1px white, inset 0px -3px 1px 1px rgba(204, 198, 197, 0.5);
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 30px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), inset 0px 4px 1px 1px white, inset 0px -3px 1px 1px rgba(204, 198, 197, 0.5);
  border-radius: 5%;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-transition: all .1s linear;
  transition: all .1s linear;
  outline: none; }

.btnNew:after {
  color: #e9e6e4;
  content: "";
  display: block;
  font-size: 30px;
  height: 3rem;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-shadow: 0px -1px 1px #bdb5b4, 1px 1px 1px white;
  position: absolute;
  width: 3rem; }

.btnNew:hover {
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#fff), to(#f4f1ee));
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #fff, #f4f1ee);
  color: #0088cc; }

.btnNew:active {
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#efedec), to(#f7f4f4));
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #efedec, #f7f4f4);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 3px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4), inset opx -3px 1px 1px rgba(204, 198, 197, 0.5);
  box-shadow: 0 3px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4), inset opx -3px 1px 1px rgba(204, 198, 197, 0.5);
  outline: none; }

.btnNew:active:after {
  color: #dbd2d2;
  text-shadow: 0px -1px 1px #bdb5b4, 0px 1px 1px white;
  outline: none; }


/* KeyFrame Animation in question */
@keyframes fade {
  0% {
    opacity: 100%; }
  100% {
    opacity: 0%; } }
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Flash</title>

    <!-- Custom CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <section class="input">
            <div class="input_title">
                <label class="input_title-label" for="title">Enter a Title</label>
                <input class="input_title-input" id="title" type="text" placeholder="List of Towels">
            </div>

            <div class="input_question">
                <label class="input_question-label" for="question">Enter a Question</label>
                <input class="input_question-input" id="question" type="text" placeholder="What is 42?">
            </div>

            <div class="input_answer">
                <label class="input_answer-label" for="answer">Enter an Answer</label>
                <input class="input_answer-input" id="answer" type="text" placeholder="The Meaning Life, Universe, and Everything">
            </div>

            <div class="input_submit flex">
                <button class="input_submit-button btnNew">Submit</button>
            </div>

            <div class="input_display"></div>

            <div class="input_start flex">
                <button type="button" class="input_start-btn btnNew" disabled>Start Quiz</button>
            </div>
        </section>

        <section class="card">
            <div class="card_container">
                <div class="front">
                    <div class="inner">
                        <p class="quiz_question">Please Set Some Questions Up</p>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="back">
                    <div class="inner">
                        <p class="quiz_answer"></p>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="card_container-guess">
                    <input type="text" class="guess_input">
                    <div class="card_container-guess-buttons">
                        <button class="submitGuess btnNew">Submit Guess</button>
                        <button class="nextQuestion btnNew">Next Question</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
    </div>


    <!-- Custom JS -->
    <script src="js/scripts.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: There are 3 possibilities if you just want a simple effect: 1-keyframe with 0% opcity, 100% opacity at 25% and 75% and 0% opacity at 100% and let it play for 3 seconds. 2- keyframes, if you want to play it you have to reset the class in your setTimeout and re-set the class, it will play automatically once set. 3- there is a way to call an event over the css but I don't know how to do it anymore.

Comment: Im still having a bit of trouble here. I got the animation working on start up when the page loads the text "please input a question...) though regardless of how I am adding or removing classes I cant seem to get it to work properly on the change of textcontent. Should I be using multiple settimeouts for this to work?

(been trying the second option)

Comment: I am using something like that in my projects. If you write `elem.className=""; elem.className="aniclass"` it should restart the animation. You can also add a listener to your css3 event, adding animationend: see https://www.sitepoint.com/css3-animation-javascript-event-handlers/

Comment: Im curious if you could show me how to do this properly? Ive been toying with it since posting and still cant get it to work. (even with the above links that is, though interesting reads for sure). I got close once using the event handlers, but I couldnt figure out how to end it the propery way.

Ive created a simple fiddle, it got all the basics there, I just need to see how its done properly and then I can figure out how to add it to my big project. 
http://jsfiddle.net/8jv2m9b3/4/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem there is that you want replace a string with another string. So you can't really fade out the first and fade in the second a the same moment. You could make another card as overflow and put it over the question card, so you have more control over the animation and text style.

I replaced the `submitGuess.addEventListener` with this one:

```
    // Event Listener to test if guess is correct
submitGuess.addEventListener("click", function() {
  if (guessInput.value.toLowerCase() === qChosen.answer.toLowerCase()) {
    card.classList.toggle("flip");
    submitGuess.disabled = true;
  } else {
    // Insert wrong message here
    cardQuestion.style.animation="colorfadeerr 0.5s ease-in-out forwards";
    // SetTimeout to reset back to Chosen Question
    setTimeout(function(){
      cardQuestion.style.animation="colorfadequestion 0.3s ease-in-out";            
    }, 1500);
  }
});

cardQuestion.addEventListener("animationstart", function() {
  if(cardQuestion.textContent === qChosen.question)
    cardQuestion.textContent = "You have guessed incorrectly. Please Try Again";
  else
    cardQuestion.textContent = qChosen.question;
});
```

And added this in the css:

```
@keyframes colorfadeerr {
  0% {
    color: rgba(255,255,255,0.0); }
  10% {
    color: rgba(255,255,255,0.0); } 
  100% {
    color: rgba(255,200,200,1.0); } 
    }

@keyframes colorfadequestion {
  0% {
    color: rgba(255,255,255,0.0); }
  30% {
    color: rgba(255,255,255,0.0); } 
  100% {
    color: rgba(255,255,255,1.0); } 
    }
```

The first animation will hide the text and show you the error message with another color. The second animation will show you the first text again (white).

I don't know if this can help you. I tried to leave it similar to your code. But as said, the effect would be nicer if you can put another card over your question. So you have a fade out of the question and a fade in of the error message at the same time.